# Bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using template from bootsnipp, I have used before, it worked fine, I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. When I tried running on Fiddle it worked, but not on my local machine.

Here is my fiddle:[Side-bar menu](https://jsfiddle.net/d1cegsm8/)
It works fine on fiddle

Here is my HTML file:

```
<title>Feedback</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
```

I have also added script before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Bootstrap relies on jQuery - have you included that too?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the scripts and stylesheets are loading properly? Are you getting any console errors in developer tools? This will normally flag up any 404's. If it is working on JSFiddle this is not a HTML/CSS question it is your local set-up.

Comment: I'm sure it's loading I can see style applied in console and I'm not getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```